JMETER Regular Expression Extracto. How can i get the specific extractor using the response i get below
Im not sure why the regexp extractor gives me a 'null' value
Response
GET http://t1vm-esource01/eSourceUAT/esoa%20printing/Reports/soa.ashx?docIndex=null&mastKey=SF8962
Heres my regular expression: .......#.
and heres the the body where i get my expression
enter image description here
"d":"\u003ctable class="list ui-custom-table" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" border="0" align="center" style="padding:0px auto;"\u003e\u003ctr\u003e\u003cth\u003eDocName\u003c/th\u003e\u003cth\u003eDocSize\u003c/th\u003e\u003cth\u003eExt\u003c/th\u003e\u003cth\u003eDocIndex\u003c/th\u003e\u003cth\u003eNoOfPages\u003c/th\u003e\u003cth\u003eSTMTDate\u003c/th\u003e\u003cth\u003eSTMType\u003c/th\u003e\u003c/tr\u003e\u003ctr onclick="getDoc(\u00273550490#1\u0027);"\u003e\u003ctd align="center"\u003eDAILY-SF8962-061625-061625\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd\u003e76967\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd\u003epdf\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd\u003e3550490#1\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd\u003e1\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd align="center"\u003e2025-06-16 00:00:00.0\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd align="center"\u003eCorporateLoanSOA\u003c/td\u003e\u003c/tr\u003e\u003ctr onclick="getDoc(\u00273550577#1\u0027);"\u003e\u003ctd align="center"\u003eWEEKLY-SF8962-061625-062225\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd\u003e76967\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd\u003epdf\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd\u003e3550577#1\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd\u003e1\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd align="center"\u003e2025-06-22 00:00:00.0\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd align="center"\u003eCorporateLoanSOA\u003c/td\u003e\u003c/tr\u003e\u003ctr onclick="getDoc(\u00273551998#1\u0027);"\u003e\u003ctd align="center"\u003eDAILY-TPD-SF8962-061725-061725\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd\u003e77270\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd\u003epdf\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd\u003e3551998#1\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd\u003e1\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd align="center"\u003e2025-06-17 00:00:00.0\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd align="center"\u003eCorporateLoanSOA\u003c/td\u003e\u003c/tr\u003e\u003ctr onclick="getDoc(\u00273552185#1\u0027);"\u003e\u003ctd align="center"\u003eDAILY-TPD-SF8962-062025-062025\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd\u003e76820\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd\u003epdf\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd\u003e3552185#1\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd\u003e1\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd align="center"\u003e2025-06-20 00:00:00.0\u003c/td\u003e\u003ctd align="center"\u003eCorporateLoanSOA\u003c/td\u003e\u003c/tr\u003e\u003c/table\u003e"
Output should be like THESE!!
enter image description here

Your regex works fine with the sample data in your question: https://regex101.com/r/hK3BPw/1

No its not working i am extracting null data as a response

Did you forget grouping? Like if you amend your "regular expression" to (.......#.) you should get what you're looking for.
Demo:

More information:

JMeter: Regular Expressions
Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter

